# Android Getting wrong value in List after comparing two list variables

Tags: java, android, listview

I have written a code using custom list view. In adapter class i m comparing variable of list 1 with list 2 and in case it matches , respective value will be fetched and shown in listview. But during this i m getting values at wrong place in list view. Pls guide what wrong i m doing?

Code for Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    List<CustomList> customListList = new ArrayList<>();
    CustomAda customAda;
    ListView listView;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ServiceSample serviceSample;
    List<NameValue> nameValues = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        customListList.add(new CustomList("name1"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name2"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name3"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name4"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name5"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name6"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name7"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name8"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name9"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name10"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name11"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name12"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name13"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name14"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name15"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name16"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name17"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name18"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name19"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name20"));
        customListList.add(new CustomList("name21"));


        nameValues.add(new NameValue("name1", 50));
        nameValues.add(new NameValue("name2", 20));

        serviceSample = new ServiceSample();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
        customAda = new CustomAda();
        listView.setAdapter(customAda);


    }

    public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    class CustomAda extends BaseAdapter {


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return customListList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return customListList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            if (layoutInflater == null) {
                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }
            if (view == null) {
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null, true);
            }
            CustomList customList = customListList.get(i);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            TextView value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv3);


            Log.i(TAG, customList.getName());

            textView.setText(customList.getName());

            for (int a = 0; a < nameValues.size(); a++) {
                if (customList.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameValues.get(a).getName())) {
                    value.setText(String.valueOf(nameValues.get(a).getValue()));
                }
            }

            if (isMyServiceRunning(ServiceSample.class, getApplicationContext())) {
                Log.i(TAG, " Alive");
                if (textView.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("name1")) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.downarr));
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uparrow));
                }


            }

            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startForegroundService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceSample.class));
                    customAda.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

and in output screen if you notice, name18,19,20 also got values where as per condition value should be available for name1 and name2 only.[image][image]

and values keep coming randomly against name position on scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int a = 0; a < nameValues.size(); a++) {
     if (customList.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameValues.get(a).getName())) {
          value.setText(String.valueOf(nameValues.get(a).getValue()));
     } else {
          value.setText("");
     }
 }
```

Updated search algorithm:

```
    boolean found = false;
    int a = 0;
    while(!found && a < nameValues.size()) {
        if (customList.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameValues.get(a).getName())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        a++;
    }

    if (found) {
        value.setText(String.valueOf(nameValues.get(a).getValue()));
    } else {
        value.setText("");
    }
```

Comment: If i add this else statement, i get only value against name2 rest all gets blank.

Comment: Yeah, because we are searching wrong. Updated answer.